# UNIFIED_PAYLOAD_FEATURE_NOT_ENABLED error when trying to set up per-envelope webhook with JSON

Tags: docusignapi

I have a working setup for sending envelopes with a per-envelope webhook EventNotification defined. I want to change the webhook message format to JSON, and I did so following [this post.](https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/connect-webhooks-json-notifications)

I added the specified EventData fields with the specified fields Version and Format. This was the only change to the EnvelopeDefinition done.

After this change the response body changed to:

`{"errorCode":"UNIFIED_PAYLOAD_FEATURE_NOT_ENABLED","message":"Connect Unified Payload Feature is not enabled for this account."}`

I've searched for this error online and I could not find any resource on it.

I am using a developer/demo account. I am following instructions on the DocuSign API support page to post here.

Answer (score 2):

Go to your **Setting** page and click **Updates** and make sure your **Send Individual Messages** is turns off: (mine is)
[image]

Comment: The request was accepted and the webhook received a JSON, nice. However I had only registered EnvelopeEvents for "Sent" and "Completed", which used to show up on the webhook (as XML), now these messages are gone and I only get a "Delivered" staus